# Concerning the q-deformations of semisimple Lie groups

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, deformation-theory, noncommutative-geometry

Recently, I came across a question on the q-analougs of finite groups of Lie type.

> > Some people say that there is no q-deformations of finite groups in the category of quantum groups which I am not sure if will also apply to the finite groups of Lie type?!

I will appreciate if someone can provide me with some refrences in this reagrd.

> > Regarding the deformation of finite groups of Lie type, can the  Quadratic Deformation or structures and approaches developled in the quantum permutation groups be helpful?

Also, there are some comments that I cannot understand:

> Why the algebras in the q-analogs cannot be defined over integers?

> Why one cannot talk about points/elements in a quantum group? And what does it have to do in our purpose in deforming finite grous in Lie type or the semisimple Lie groups?

Comment: It would be helpful if you linked to your sources for these questions. The original context may be helpful for understanding these questions, and if they come from another Math StackExchange or MathOverflow question, some of the answers there may actually be adequate.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thank you for your comment! These are from a private conversation on which currently I don't have an access!